# Aliasing a nested module and parent module

Tags: elixir

I am currently attempting to alias a module (A) and a module nested in that module (A.B) is there a way to do this in on line?

```
defmodule A do ... end
defmodule A.B do ... end

defmodule C do
  alias A
  alias A.B
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of *nested* modules in Elixir in the first place. `A.B` module has literally nothing in common with `A` module, save for using it’s name as a namespace.

But what you are asking is still somewhat possible for deeply namespaced modules.

```rb
defmodule A do               
  defmodule B do               
    def b, do: IO.puts :b        
    defmodule C do       
      def c, do: IO.puts :c 
    end
  end
end
```

For the code above one might [`Kernel.SpecialForms.alias/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#alias/2) both `A.B` and `A.B.C` within the single call:

```rb
alias A.{B, B.C}             
#⇒ [A.B, A.B.C]
C.c
#⇒ c
```

The same syntax would work for [`Kernel.SpecialForms.require/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#require/2), [`Kernel.SpecialForms.import/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2), and [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.use/2).

Unfortunately, the trick with curlies does not work on a top level (`alias {A, A.B}` won’t work.) Maybe it’d be a good PR to Elixir core.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
`A` is not the parent module of `A.B` in Elixir.

Module 's `.` is only a name, and you can just use it for understanding A is B's parent module literally.